# Algebraic independence of $E_2$, $E_4$ and $E_6$

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms, quasimodular-forms

In "M. Kaneko and D. Zagier, A generalized Jacobi theta function and quasimodular forms, Prog. Math. 129,
165-172 (1995)" there is a proposition stating essentially that $E_2$, $E_4$ and $E_6$ are algebraically independent.

Unfortunately there is no proof there. I know how to show the algebraic independence of $E_4$ and $E_6$.

How does the proof for $E_2$ work?

Comment: Dear Jonas, Since $E_2$ is not a modular form, but has a "near-modular" transformation law under $\tau \mapsto -1/\tau$, it shouldn't be hard to deduce the independence by writing down a putative algebraic relation between $E_2$, $E_4$, and $E_6$ (so this is a polynomial in $E_2$ whose coefficients are sums of modular forms of
various weights which vanishes) and then applying $\tau \mapsto -1/\tau$ to the relation and seeing what happens.  Regards,

Comment: Dear Emerton Well that's the obvious approach yes. I didn't find it so "easy".
Can you be more specific? Is there a trick?
For $E_4$ and $E_6$ one evaluates at $\frac{-1}{\tau+m}$ for enough $m$'s to
write it as a Vandermonde matrix applied to a vector of forms to show that one
can assume homogenous weights wlog (after that it is much easier). I find it a bit harder to find such an invertible matrix for $E_2$
(resp. to show that it is invertible).

Comment: Dear Jonas, To expand slightly on Emerton's comment, $E_4$ and $E_6$ are modular forms, so in particular $E_4(-1/\tau)=\tau^4 E_4(\tau)$ and $E_6(-1/\tau)= \tau^6 E_6(\tau)$. On the other hand $E_2$ is not a modular form, it is only quasimodular. It obeys $E_2(-1/\tau)= \tau^2 E_2(\tau)- 6 i \tau/\pi$. No algebraic combination of $E_4,E_6$ can transform this way under $\tau \rightarrow -1/\tau$ so $E_2$ is algebraically independent of $E_4,E_6$.

Comment: Dear Jonas, For $E_4$ and $E_6$ one uses that $\tau \mapsto -1/\tau$ takes $f(\tau)$ to $\tau^k f(\tau)$ for a weight $k$ modular forms, 
and this implies that in any sum of modular forms of various weights, the different weight terms are linearly independent (because they multiply by different powers of $\tau$).  I don't really see where Vandermonde matrices come into it (although maybe that's one way of making the previous sentence rigorous, although there are other ways that I find easier).  Now if you add in $E_2$, it is a bit more complicated, but shouldn't be too bad.  Regards,

Comment: P.S.  Here is how I would do the $E_4$ and $E_6$ case: let $f_{k_1} + \cdots f_{k_n} = 0$ be a linear dependence between modular forms of increasing weights $k_1 < k_2 < \cdots < k_n$.  Now evaluate at $-1/\tau$, and divide by $\tau^{k_1}$, to get
$f_{k_1} + \tau^{k_2 - k_1} f_{k_2} + \cdots \tau^{k_n - k_1} f_{k_n}  = 0.$ Subtracting the two equations, you get a linear dependence relation with fewer terms, and a well-organized induction should finish.

Comment: Dear Jeff

The fact that no algebraic combination of $E_4$ and $E_6$ can transform this way doesn't imply that $E_2$, $E_4$ and $E_6$ are algebraically independant... Regards.

Comment: Dear Emerton

Your suggested proof is indeed not rigorous. I illustrate the proof with the Vandermonde matrix here: We want to show that the algebra of modular forms is given by a direct sum of the weight components. So let $f_0+\dots+f_n=0$ for weights $0$ up to $n$. Let $f$ denote the vector with components $f_i$. Evaluate the sum at $\frac{-1}{\tau+m}$, applying modularity this gives: $\sum_{i=0}^n(\tau+m)^if_i=0$. If we let $m=0,\dots,m$ this can be written as $Af=0$ where $A$ is the Vandermonde-matrix with entries $(\tau+m)^i$. It has a nonzero determinant, so $f=A^{-1}0=0$.

Comment: After that it only remains to show that no homogenous polynomial in $E_4$ and $E_6$ can be zero which follows easily because such a non-zero polynomial of minimal degree can be written as $aE_4^n+bE_4E_6P(E_4,E_6)+cE_6^m=0$. Evaluating at $i$ and $\rho$ gives $a=c=0$ which reduces it to a lower degree polynomial which gives a contradiction.

However with E_2 this approach becomes much more complicated. :-(

Regards.

Comment: Dear Jonas, I don't know why you say my suggested proof is not rigorous.  Do you want me to spell out the "well-organized induction"?  Regards,

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to be rude.

The first is a linear dependence over $\mathbb{C}$. If you substract you get a linear dependence with coefficients involving powers of τ. If you try to do this properly I think you essentially end up with the Vandermonde matrix method. But yes your approach would work if you instead apply the slash operator with the weight for the highest term. This shows that the remaining difference is a modular form of weight k (so zero because we already took all parts of weight k). Which reduces it to the homogenous case. However all those approaches fail for E2... :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a reference for the algebraic independance of $E_2,E_4,E_6$ over $\mathbf{C}$ :

[MR2186573 (2007a:11065)  Martin, François ;  Royer, Emmanuel . Formes modulaires et périodes.
(French)  [Modular forms and periods]  Formes modulaires et transcendance, 
 1--117, Sémin. Congr., 12, Soc. Math. France, Paris,  2005.](http://smf4.emath.fr/Publications/SeminairesCongres/2005/12/pdf/smf_sem-cong_12_1-117.pdf)

See Lemme 117 p. 80. The proof is along the lines suggested by Emerton.

Comment: Nice to know that this book is available for free.

Comment: Thanks a lot! :-)

However I would not say that it is similar or as simple as suggested by Emerton. In fact it uses a different description for the space of quasimodular forms than polynomials in $E_2$, $E_4$ and $E_6$ (in fact the equality is shown much later on p. 83 Corollary 121). When trying to show the direct sum property the function is in essence evaluated at $\frac{-1}{\tau+m}$ for infinitely many $m$ ("closer to the Vandermonde idea"). So all in all the proof is rather complicated. I'm just saying this in my defense. I really do/did appreciate Emerton's effort to help! Best